# Sending JSON data with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Simple request being made

```
    var username = {'username' : 'tom'};

    var request = $.ajax({
        url      : 'test.php',
        method   : 'GET',
        data     : JSON.stringify(username),
        dataType : 'json'
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response);
    });

    request.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("bar" => "bar"));
?>
```

Still getting error, no idea why

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK I think I'm on to something

Comment: nevermind no luck yet

Comment: Simplified the code

Answer (score 4):

that's because the server is returning a non valid JSON string. Try to check what the server is returning. This may happen if your server is throwing an error. In your case, I think the `error` you are trying to parse is not a JSON string. You might want to check that out as well. 
You can use [this link](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: Well here is your problem, What is the value of the error variable ?

Comment: I commented out the server code. I believe the problem lies around `data : JSON.stringify({username : username}),`

Comment: When I change `dataType: json` to html it works. The weird thing is the server is not even giving a response, because I commented the code out for debugging but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I think it's the `JSON.parse(error)` try commenting that out.

Comment: Commented it out but am still not getting a response from the server and I uncommented the server code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is server side if you are not getting any response.

Comment: not really because when I change dataType: html it works

Comment: does the server returns a valid JSON string ?